# IDE Putting black lines following my location -Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have lines of black following where I am typing on Pycharm.  It slowly gets larger the farther I go down the line of code.  How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I'm pretty sure I know what you are talking about, just want to make sure.

Comment: @chrisz I can't upload a picture my app keeps crashing and there is no Wi-Fi here

Comment: OK. I would recommend going to File->Settings->Editor->Color-Scheme->Editor->Carat Row, and see if that got changed to a darker color.

Comment: Ok I will try during break and get back to you, thank you